# How deep do the roots of weeds grow in a lawn?

Tags: lawn, weeds, sod

How deep in the soil do the roots of weeds grow? Would getting rid of top 3 inches of lawn and putting in triple mix and sod get rid of weeds? (Our lawn has more weeds than grass).

Comment: Maybe you can write a new question about how to get rid of weed in your lawn, and you should include some photos, and how do you care your lawn. This question may or maybe not help you: it depends on weeds (annuals, perennials), but some weeds will not growth from deep-cut roots (but some yes). It is complex, so you may ask directly what do you want.

Comment: with the name herbicide phobic i would also assume that you do not want to use herbicides for controlling the deeper rooted and more hard to kill weed species.

Answer (score 1):

Plants with only three inches of root depth are not going to survive hot and dry weather in the wild (i.e. not growing in lawns watered by sprinkler systems), and the common feature of "weeds" is that they survive better than most other plants.

Weeds with tap roots will be much deeper than 3 inches. For example dandelion roots typically go down 6 to 18 inches, but can grow as deep as 10 feet or more!

Comment: the other important point to understand about weeds is that they are the early colonizers of disturbed and poor soils so while they may not survive long it may be long enough for them to grow, set seeds and spread those seeds.  in my area we have several very tiny weeds which can grow and give seeds in not much space at all.  things like purselane and spring whitlow grass can grow in amazing places and you end up with a lot of seeds from those.